# instanceof with generic collection

Tags: java

Why would the following snippet not compile ?

```
if (mangoList instanceof List<Mango>) { System.out.println("true"); }
```

- You don't know that mangoList is a List type.
- The instanceof keyword only works on primitive types.
- You can only check the type of collections using reflection.
- Generic types are erased before runtime.(ans)
- The statement could cause mangoList to be set to an instance of a List.

Which do you think is the correct answer ?

Comment: Which do _you_ think is the correct answer? Why?

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer is the one that you marked `ans`. You will be able to tell that `mangoList` is a `List`, but you wouldn't be able to get the type of its erased argument. The remaning choices do not make sense.

Comment: Great, yeah that is what I was guessing ..thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Yes "Generic types are erased during run time".

**2.** So you wont be able to tell the type of the List.

**3.** But you will be able recognize that mangoList is a List.

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, use mangoList instanceof List to check if it is a List with some type.  This is useful if you aren't sure if you've got a List or a Mango object, for example, but will not distinguish between types of Lists.  To do that, I advise you check the first element for its type.